# syncfusion flutter pdf is not creating pdf on hindi words

Tags: flutter, pdf, syncfusion

syncfusion flutter pdf is not creating pdf on hindi words even i have used -

final Uint8List fontData = File('assets/Font/Noto.ttf').readAsBytesSync();
final PdfFont contentFont = PdfTrueTypeFont(fontData, 9);
output of text in hindi but not in proper[image: output like in image inccorect word like dawara]

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.